# How do I fix Serana's yellow eye problem?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I had Serana cure herself of vampirism, she came back as a very useful character: I can heal her, she's invincible and she still uses her health drain powers.  However, her eyes totally creep me out: she has the green irises but the "whites" are glowing yellow at me.  It's like she has nuclear jaundice.

How can I fix her eyes to something more sensible?  Human eyes are preferable (green + white) but at this point, I'm looking for anything that's less creepy.

Comment: if this is for PC then a simple mod would do the trick, if this is for consoles then I'm not sure... give her a helmet?

Comment: Didn't play this part of the game yet, but is this a question about modifying companions in general or does this character actually provide some options for modifying her already?

Comment: @Krjax, I'd consider it a bug (if low priority), much like the missing wolf howls in the DLCs.  She's supposed to be human after the cure and instead looks very strange indeed.  Most humans don't have eyes that glow in the dark.

Answer (score 6):

You can fix the eyes with mods on at least the [PC](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/31477/?) or [Xbox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3266131).

Comment: I love how PC has mods for anything and everything... want to tweak eye color? yep. want to make dragons thomas the tank engine? no problem.

Comment: @JLaBella psssh, there are much crazier (and funner) mods than turning dragons into thomas the tank engine.  Try [super mario world](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/24709/‎)

Comment: A similar [mod](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3266131) is available for the XBox One (but not the PS4... sorry guys.)

Answer (score -3):

You could just give her a dragon priest mask or any helmet that covers the face like guards or the masque of clavicus vile . or just get a new follower